# Asp.net export to csv and culture

Tags: asp.net, csv, export, culture

I'm exporting data to a csv file using Asp.net and I need to know from the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture if I should use "," or ";" as a value separator. For example US needs "," and Europe needs ";". How can I find out which one to use from the CurrentCulture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
```

Definition from the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.listseparator.aspx):

> Gets or sets the string that separates items in a list.